# How to bring all the app's windows to front when making active just one?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

In my application I have 4-5 windows on screen simultaneously. Sometimes while working some of the windows can go back behind some other app's windows (behind xcode or safari for example). Then, when I make one of my application's window active other 3-4 windows remain on the back.

Is there any way I can bring all the app's windows to front, when I make one of them active?

p.s. I know I can use [NSApp windows] and just call orderFrontRegardless in the loop, but I don't know how to catch the moment when one of my windows becomes active.

Any kind of help or a hint is really appreciated!

Comment: The `NSApplicationWillBecomeActiveNotification ` and `NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notifications of NSApplication tell you when the application became active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does the trick for me:

```
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // TODO: go over windows here and bring them active
    for (NSWindow * window in  [NSApp orderedWindows]) {
        [window orderFrontRegardless];
    }
}
```

don't forget to set up the file to be the app's delegate in order for this code to work.